# C# ListView sorting

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have 2 ListViews and im adding selected items from one to another. First ListView, lets call it `availableJobs` and the second ListView `selectedJobs`. Person can select job/jobs from first ListView and move it to the second one. Now what i would like is that the sorting should stay allso same with as it was in the first ListView. In te first `availableJobs` the jobs are sorted by the Job ID i just want to keep that sorting allso in the `selectedJobs` TreeView.

For example:

1)I select Job with ID 3 and move it to the `selectedJobs` TreeView
2)I select Job with ID 1 and move it to the `selectedJobs`

Now what happens is that the order in the `selectedJobs` will be:

Job 3
Job 1

What i need is tht when i add Job with ID 1 it would go in from of the Job with ID 3.

I tried to use a custom Comparer:

```
    public class IntegerComparer : IComparer
    {
        private int _colIndex;
        public IntegerComparer(int colIndex)
        {
            _colIndex = colIndex;
        }
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            int nx = int.Parse((x as ListViewItem).SubItems[_colIndex].Text);
            int ny = int.Parse((y as ListViewItem).SubItems[_colIndex].Text);
            return nx.CompareTo(ny);
        }
    }
```

But the problem with that is that it puts Job with id 10, 11 etc before 2, 3 and etc..

Comment: Perhaps instead of using `Add()`, get the index of the next higher job in the selected list and do an `InserAt()` at index - 1.

Comment: How are you using that comparer? Are there some sorted columns on the listview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sorting feature of the ListView:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx

or insetad of adding the job straight from the ListView1 to the ListView2 you could populate a list of LineItem(or a tailored object) ordered by Id and you could use that list as DataSource for the ListView2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom sorting.To do this, you must implement IComparer class and set ListViewItemSorter property. Following link has a sample implementation:

http://csharpexamples.com/c-sort-listview-items-columns/